# What exactly does s2k do in gpg

Tags: hash, symmetric, key-derivation, pgp, s2k

So I recently discovered the `--s2k` mode in `gpg`. 
Sadly it is not very well-documented. I mean, what is `s2k` even supposed to mean?

Could someone explain to me the purpose and detailed function of `s2k`?

1. Is `--s2k-cipher-algo` even necessary in a symmetric encryption scenario where you define the cipher separately?
2. What **exactly**  does `--s2k-count` do?
3. What does the number after `--s2k-count` do? What does it indicate and why is 65 million the highest number? 65 million of what? What is done so many times?

Comment: Related https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15632/what-is-purpose-of-s2k-gnupg-options

Comment: I´ve read this !

Comment: What in `man gpg` is confusing / unclear about these options?

Comment: Its not well enough documented , I would like to learn more about this

Comment: The description for `--s2k-count n` pretty clearly answers questions 2 through 4...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The "s2k" options correspond to the [String-to-Key specifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1). An s2k transform turns a human-compatible symmetric secret (a password or passphrase) into a symmetric key suitable for a symmetric encryption or MAC algorithm.

Turning passwords into keys is tricky business because passwords that human can remember and accept to type tend to be weak with regards to exhaustive search (often called "dictionary attacks" in that context, since we are talking about *words*). Thus, we need a "strengthened" process which is often called "password hashing" or "password-based key derivation". To be brief, a good password hashing process must:

1. be unique to each case, to prevent precomputations and cost sharing;
2. be awfully expensive, in a configurable way.

Read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) for an introduction to the relevant concepts of password hashing.

---

The `s2k-count` parameter is used only when the s2k method is "3", i.e. [Iterated and Salted S2K](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.3) in OpenPGP terminology. This password hashing method basically hashes together multiple copies of the salt and the password, concatenated, until the total byte count reaches the specified value. With the maximum value (65011712), about 65 MB worth of data are thus hashed; a modern machine (even a "small" one like a smartphone) should be able to do that in a fraction of a second (say, less than half a second), so this is tolerable from a user interface point of view. However, the attacker will *also* need to do that heavy hashing for each trial of a potential password; and for him, there is a *huge* difference between half a second and a millionth of a second, because he has many potential passwords to try.

Now that S2K is not the best in town, because smart attackers will get a substantial boost in their attack by using some GPU (GPU are *very good* at running hash functions like SHA-1). But this is the best one defined so far in the OpenPGP format.

The `--s2k-cipher-algo` is about informing the S2K transform about the kind of key it must produce: while symmetric keys are mostly bunches of bits, their length still depends on the intended algorithm (e.g. a key for AES-256 must have 256 bits in length).

Comment: so to ensure my understanding a little bit let me try to restate in comp-sci laymans... in the case where aes-256 is used the "string to key" must take a string as input and output "a key [with] 256 bits", correct?

Answer (score 3):

s2k = "string to key", so a password is transformed into a key for a symmetric cipher. 
It's documented in RFC4880. The "count" is the number of bytes hashed in each hashing step, which is only relevant for the most secure and default s2k-version, salted and iterated.